# Problem with react-hook-form - form submit fails often

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongodb, express

I am using **useForm** from https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-hook-form, and sometimes it works right away, sometimes I gotta refresrh the page and then it works, and sometimes it doesn't work at all, here's a code snippet:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './AdminPageStyle.css';

import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

import { shakingInputAnimation, addAnimation, updateAnimation } from './functionality';

const AdminPage = () => {
    document.title = 'Admin page';
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

    return(
        <main className="main_class">
            <h1>Hello admin!</h1>        

            {/* Panel for adding new animation */}
            <div className="add_class" style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                <h3>Add new animation</h3>
                <form className="form_class" onSubmit={handleSubmit(addAnimation)}>
                    <div className="input-field_class">
                        <label className="label_class" htmlFor="add-name_id">Add name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="animationName" id="add-name_id" placeholder="Awesome animation" ref={register({required: true})}/>
                        {
                            errors.animationName && 
                            shakingInputAnimation(document.getElementById('add-name_id'))
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field_class">
                        <label className="label_class" htmlFor="add-gifAddress_id">Add gif address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="gifAddress" id="add-gifAddress_id" placeholder="/images/animation_gifs/loader.png" ref={register({required: true})}/>
                        {
                            errors.gifAddress && 
                            shakingInputAnimation(document.getElementById('add-gifAddress_id'))
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field_class">
                        <label className="label_class" htmlFor="add-description_id">Add description</label>
                        <input type="text" name="description" id="add-description_id" placeholder="Button hover animation" ref={register({required: true})}/>
                        {
                            errors.description &&
                            shakingInputAnimation(document.getElementById('add-description_id'))
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field_class">
                        <label className="label_class" htmlFor="add-link-to-page_id">Add link to page</label>
                        <input type="text" name="linkToPage" id="add-link-to-page_id" placeholder="/animations/animated-button.html" ref={register({required: true})}/>
                        {
                            errors.linkToPage &&
                            shakingInputAnimation(document.getElementById('add-link-to-page_id'))
                        }
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" className="add-new-animation_class" value="Make new animation"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
```

Here's a addAnimation function, that is properly exported from other file:

```
export function addAnimation({ animationName, gifAddress, description, linkToPage }) {
    console.log(animationName, gifAddress, description, linkToPage)
    if (!animationName || !gifAddress || !description || !linkToPage) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            alert('You must fill in all fields');
        }, 800);
        return;
    }
    // send data to db to make new animation new animation

    (async() => {
        await fetch('http://localhost:8080/animations', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: animationName,
                description: description,
                gifAddress: gifAddress,
                linkToPage: linkToPage
            })
        });
    })();
    setTimeout(() => {
        window.location.reload();
    }, 300);
}
```

Backend that's handling this:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const animationSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: String,
    gifAddress: String,
    description: String,
    linkToAnimationPage: String
});

const Animation = mongoose.model('animations', animationSchema);

router.post('/', async(req, res) => {
    const animation = await new Animation({
        name: req.body.name,
        gifAddress: req.body.gifAddress,
        description: req.body.description,
        linkToAnimationPage: req.body.linkToPage
    });
    animation.save(function(err) {
        if (err) return handleError(err);
        // saved!
    });
});
```

**AS I SAID:** everything works properly except useForm hook sometimes sends the data, and sometimes doesn't

Comment: The sometimes part is strange. It sounds strange but may be your browser is the reason. Try to turn your computer off and on again to see if the issue still persist.

Comment: @kunquan, that is the problem, yesterday worked, day before didn't, now it doesn't work, that may be a problem since this project is suppose to go live, I can't ship unstable code in production

Comment: Try to remove the `window.location.reload` and see if it work.

Comment: @kunquan I tried it now, it still doesn't work, but it worked yesterday, the problem is definitely within the form

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the `addAnimation` function. Does that function get called every time you submit the form (check the log)? If it's, then try to remove everything in that function except the `fetch` (put the `fetch` outside of the IIFE)

Comment: @kunquan it doesn't log anything when I click submit, when it logs then action is sucesful, but when nothing happens(when it doesn't send) it logs nothing

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can guess, the problem either is in the `<form>` itself or the `addAnimation` function. I suggest you change your code to "barebone" as below and check the logging.

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './AdminPageStyle.css';

import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';


const AdminPage = () => {
    document.title = 'Admin page';
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

    return(
        <main className="main_class">
            <h1>Hello admin!</h1>        

            {/* Panel for adding new animation */}
            <div className="add_class" style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                <h3>Add new animation</h3>
                <form className="form_class" onSubmit={() => console.log('The submit work')}>
                    <div className="input-field_class">
                        <label className="label_class" htmlFor="add-name_id">Add name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="animationName" id="add-name_id" placeholder="Awesome animation" ref={register({required: true})}/>
                       
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field_class">
                        <label className="label_class" htmlFor="add-gifAddress_id">Add gif address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="gifAddress" id="add-gifAddress_id" placeholder="/images/animation_gifs/loader.png" ref={register({required: true})}/>
                                               
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field_class">
                        <label className="label_class" htmlFor="add-description_id">Add description</label>
                        <input type="text" name="description" id="add-description_id" placeholder="Button hover animation" ref={register({required: true})}/>
                        
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field_class">
                        <label className="label_class" htmlFor="add-link-to-page_id">Add link to page</label>
                        <input type="text" name="linkToPage" id="add-link-to-page_id" placeholder="/animations/animated-button.html" ref={register({required: true})}/>
                        
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" className="add-new-animation_class" value="Make new animation"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
```

If you can see the logging every time you submit the form, which mean there is nothing wrong with the form at this state. Move on to the next step, which is adding more function to the `form`

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import './AdminPageStyle.css';

import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

import { shakingInputAnimation, addAnimation, updateAnimation } from './functionality';

const AdminPage = () => {
    document.title = 'Admin page';
    const { register, handleSubmit, errors } = useForm();

    return(
        <main className="main_class">
            <h1>Hello admin!</h1>        

            {/* Panel for adding new animation */}
            <div className="add_class" style={{display: 'flex'}}>
                <h3>Add new animation</h3>
                <form className="form_class" onSubmit={() => console.log('Submit success')}>
                    <div className="input-field_class">
                        <label className="label_class" htmlFor="add-name_id">Add name</label>
                        <input type="text" name="animationName" id="add-name_id" placeholder="Awesome animation" ref={register({required: true})}/>
                        {
                            errors.animationName && 
                            shakingInputAnimation(document.getElementById('add-name_id'))
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field_class">
                        <label className="label_class" htmlFor="add-gifAddress_id">Add gif address</label>
                        <input type="text" name="gifAddress" id="add-gifAddress_id" placeholder="/images/animation_gifs/loader.png" ref={register({required: true})}/>
                        {
                            errors.gifAddress && 
                            shakingInputAnimation(document.getElementById('add-gifAddress_id'))
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field_class">
                        <label className="label_class" htmlFor="add-description_id">Add description</label>
                        <input type="text" name="description" id="add-description_id" placeholder="Button hover animation" ref={register({required: true})}/>
                        {
                            errors.description &&
                            shakingInputAnimation(document.getElementById('add-description_id'))
                        }
                    </div>
                    <div className="input-field_class">
                        <label className="label_class" htmlFor="add-link-to-page_id">Add link to page</label>
                        <input type="text" name="linkToPage" id="add-link-to-page_id" placeholder="/animations/animated-button.html" ref={register({required: true})}/>
                        {
                            errors.linkToPage &&
                            shakingInputAnimation(document.getElementById('add-link-to-page_id'))
                        }
                    </div>
                    <input type="submit" className="add-new-animation_class" value="Make new animation"/>
                </form>
            </div>
        </main>
```

If you can still get the logging every time you submit the form, which indicate that there is nothing wrong with the `form` and the problem probably in the `addAnimation`. Next step would be rework on that function. Keep the original `form` you post above and change the `addAnimation` function to.

```js
export function addAnimation({ animationName, gifAddress, description, linkToPage }) {
      console.log('addAnimation run')
       fetch('http://localhost:8080/animations', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Accept': 'application/json',
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: JSON.stringify({
                name: animationName,
                description: description,
                gifAddress: gifAddress,
                linkToPage: linkToPage
            })
        });
}
```

Comment: Tried all of this, but it's not working still, thanks for help anyway